# NFS - Access denied by server when mounting external drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, mount, nfs

I have a fileserver and want to share an external HDD connected to the fileserver with my clients using NFS. I'm already sharing a few internal HDDs set up with ZFS shared to my hosts and they are all working.

Host is running Ubuntu Server 21.04

Client is running Debian 10.

Host config:

/etc/exports

```
/home/fish/iron  192.168.1.21(rw,fsid=21,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
/srv/uranium    192.168.1.21(rw,fsid=212,no_subtree_check)
```

I have made sure to run `exportfs -ra` after each modification. `crossmnt` was added based on suggestions from reading through many other questions on Superuser and other websites.

Client config:

/etc/fstab

```
192.168.1.40:/home/fish/iron  /home/fish/iron  nfs   rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,_netdev 0 0
192.168.1.40:/srv/uranium  /backup  nfs   rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,_netdev 0 0
```

The `/srv/uranium` mount works flawlessly, and is a part of my ZFS pool, but `/home/fish/iron` refuses to mount with error: `mount.nfs: access denied by server while mountin 192.168.1.40:/home/fish/iron`

Output of `showmount -e 192.168.1.40`

```
/srv/uranium    192.168.1.21
/home/fish/iron 192.168.1.21
```

Mounting "manually" without going through fstab results in the same error.

Not included in this post is a plethora of other shares I've successfully mounted with many other clients, all on the ZFS pool. the NFS service itself is functioning, but the external HDD refuses to share.

Comment: 1) crossmnt is only necessary for allowing "automatic" access to sub-mounts of the exported mount, and is only necessary for NFSv3 – not for NFSv4; 2) your rsize/wsize seems _tiny,_ why not just use the system default values?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I removed crossmnt and increased my rsize/wsize (their size were tiny for legacy reasons) though the issue persists.

Comment: Do you have access to the server's rpc.mountd logs? That's the service which verifies access during mount requests, for all NFS versions. Can you configure `[mountd] debug="all"` in /etc/nfs.conf? _(Some new servers might be running rpc.exportd instead; that's a v4-only variant of mountd.)_

Comment: Is `/home/fish/iron` or `/home/fish` or `/home` mounted as FUSE on the server? What is the filesystem of the "external HDD connected to the fileserver"? How do you mount it?